# Inputted string also assigned to an integer?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a rock-paper-scissors program that is a best two out of three where the computer randomly rolls a 0-2 and each of those are assigned to rock, paper, or scissors, and then it compares the userInput and counts a win for computer or player then adds it up.

BUT, I can't figure out how to make it that if user were to enter "scissors" the program would know that it's also assigned to 2 (For comparison purposes).

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int gameCount = 0;
    int computerWins = 0;
    int playerWins = 0;
    int rock = 0;
    int paper = 1;
    int scissors = 2;
    int playerChoice;
    int computerChoice = r.nextInt(3);

    System.out.println("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors! Best 2 out of 3!");

    while (gameCount >= 0 && gameCount < 3)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\", or \"Scissors\"");
        break;
    }
       playerChoice = userInput.nextInt()

        //If player enters anything besides rock, paper, or scissors
        if (playerChoice < 0 || playerChoice >= 3) {
            System.out.println("That wasn't an option");
            computerWins++;
            gameCount++;

          //The game goes on, and the winners are added up!
        } else if (playerChoice == 0 && computerChoice == 1) {
            computerWins++;
            gameCount++;
            System.out.println("Rock v Paper! Computer Wins!\n" +
                    "Player has won " + playerWins + " times and the computer " +
                    "has won " + computerWins + " times");
        } else if (playerChoice == 1 && computerChoice == 0) {
            playerWins++;
            gameCount++;
            System.out.println("Paper v Rock! Player Wins!\n" +
                    "Player has won " + playerWins + " times and the computer " +
                    "has won " + computerWins + " times");
        } else if (playerChoice == 1 && computerChoice == 2) {
            computerWins++;
            gameCount++;
            System.out.println("Paper v Scissors! Computer Wins!\n" +
                    "Player has won " + playerWins + " times and the computer " +
                    "has won " + computerWins + " times");
        } else if (playerChoice == 2 && computerChoice == 1) {
            playerWins++;
            gameCount++;
            System.out.println("Scissors v Paper! Player Wins!\n" +
                    "Player has won " + playerWins + " times and the computer " +
                    "has won " + computerWins + " times");
        } else if (playerChoice == 2 && computerChoice == 0) {
            computerWins++;
            gameCount++;
            System.out.println("Scissors v Rock! Computer Wins!\n" +
                    "Player has won " + playerWins + " times and the computer " +
                    "has won " + computerWins + " times");
        } else if (playerChoice == 0 && computerChoice == 2) {
            playerWins++;
            gameCount++;
            System.out.println("Rock v Scissors! Player Wins!\n" +
                    "Player has won " + playerWins + " times and the computer " +
                    "has won " + computerWins + " times");
        } else if (playerChoice == 0 && computerChoice == 0) {
            gameCount++;
            System.out.println("Rock v Rock! Tie!\n" +
                    "Player has won " + playerWins + " times and the computer " +
                    "has won " + computerWins + " times");
        } else if (playerChoice == 1 && computerChoice == 1) {
            gameCount++;
            System.out.println("Paper v Paper! Tie!\n" +
                    "Player has won " + playerWins + " times and the computer " +
                    "has won " + computerWins + " times");
        } else if (playerChoice == 2 && computerChoice == 2) {
            gameCount++;
            System.out.println("Paper v Paper! Tie!\n" +
                    "Player has won " + playerWins + " times and the computer " +
                    "has won " + computerWins + " times");
        }

        //Check if game count reaches max games then chooses a winner
        if (gameCount == 3 && computerWins > playerWins) {
            System.out.println("The Computer Wins!");
        } else if (gameCount == 3 && computerWins < playerWins) {
            System.out.println("The Player Wins!");
        } else if (gameCount == 3 && computerWins == playerWins) {
            System.out.println("The game is a tie!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at enums, they will solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of `playerChoice = userInput.nextInt();` try this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = sc.nextLine();
try {
    playerChoice = Integer.parseInt(input);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")) {
        playerChoice = rock;
    } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")) {
        playerChoice = paper;
    } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")) {
        playerChoice = scissors;
    } else {
        // if input is invalid
        playerChoice = -1;
    }
}
```

Since you're using `userInput.nextInt()` and `playerChoice` is an int and can only hold ints, you need to parse your user's input. In this case, `Integer.parseInt(input)` will try to find an int in the user input. If it can't it will return an exception; that's why there's a try-catch block. If it isn't an int, it will look for each string and assign the associated int value to `playerChoice` or -1 if the input is invalid. Then the rest of your code should be able to appropriately handle the playerChoice after that.

Comment: Thank ya! I'll make it happen!